# Moq fake one method but use real implementation of another

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

Given an interface `IService` that has `Method1()` and `Method2()`.

I want to test that when `Method1()` throws an `Exception`, `Method2(`) is called and **returns a given value**.

(`Method2()` is called when `Method1()` throws).

Therefore I need to test a real `Method2()` with a fake `Method1()`, they are methods of the same interface.

Here is my test code:

`MBase sut.MethodX()` is the only entry point. It uses `IService`.

My aim is to assert that `Method2()` returns *something*.

```
// Arrange
// Fake bytes in.
var networkStreamMock = new Mock<INetworkStream>();
networkStreamMock.Method1(x => x.Read(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(It.IsAny<byte[]>());

// Force throw TimeoutException.
var mock = new Mock<IService>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Method1(new Message
{ 
    Xml = Xml,  
}
)).Throws<TimeoutException>();

// Check Method 2 is called. (this is done in its own test so commented out)
// mock.Setup(m => m.Method2(It.IsAny<Message>())).Verifiable();

// New MBase.
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new FakeBindings());
kernel.Rebind<IService>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
MBase sut = kernel.Get<M>();

// Act
sut.MethodX(networkStreamMock.Object);

// Here I would like to assert on the return value of Method2
mock.Verify(m => m.Method2(It.IsAny<Message>()));
```

Is this possible with Moq or another mocking framework? How do I do it? 
I can create a manual mock with a fake implementation of `Method1()` and a real implementation of `Method2()` but I wonder if there is a better approach.

I have already tested `IService` in isolation but I now wish to test it's interaction with `MBase`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
var mock = new Mock<MyNetworkStream>(){ CallBase = true };
mock.Setup(m => m.Method1....
```

The above code will use the real implementation of MyNetworkStream for any method/property which is not explicitly setup. I.e. it'll call the real Method2(), while the Method1() will be the mocked version.

`CallBase=true` is usually meant to test abstract classes (if this is right or wrong, is out of the scope of this question).

Comment: If the class `MyNetworkStream` implements `Method1` by a public method which does *not* have the `virtual` (or `abstract` or `override`) modifier, can you still setup this `Method1` on a `Mock<MyNetworkStream>`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, no I don't think you can. In my case both my methods are coming from an abstract class.

Comment: You mean ?

var mock = new Mock<INetworkStream>(){ CallBase = true };

Comment: this only works if the methods are virtual in the class. I think OP want to mock the interface that the class inherits from, without modifying the class implementation to make the methods virtual.

Answer (score 12):

In this case (unless there's a lot more going on) I would just create my own test class extending the class with the real behavior, that implements the interface you need to mock. This way you can mock the one value, and fallback to the base class for the real functionality.