# How to use Moq to have an ability to use method operation of mocked object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an instantiation in constructor in test:

```
public class Car{

public string Method()
{
 return "test";
}
}

private readonly ICar _classUnderTest;
    public CarTests()
    {
        var collaboratingClass = new CollaboratingClass();
        _classUnderTest = new Car(collaboratingClass );
    }
```

If I use moq and pass mock instance like this:

```
    var collaboratingClass = new Mock<ICollaboratingClass>();
    _classUnderTest = new Car(collaboratingClass .Object);
```

...then I can't call method. The method from this mocked instance is not being called, so I can't use it for calculation. How can I make my mock object to be able to access method and do operation with mock object?

As you can see I don't want to have concrete dependencies here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moq fake one method but use real implementation of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054563/moq-fake-one-method-but-use-real-implementation-of-another)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake a return to your mocked class method. If you need the behavior from your dependency, it's no longer a unit test